# minipage inside an mdframed with a footnote

Tags: floats, captions, minipage, mdframed, xepersian

I need to have captioned tables inside an `mdframed` environment. Since floats cannot be used, I am using `captionof` alongside `tabular`. The caption and the `tabular` might get separated, when there is a page break (as in the MWE below). In order to prevent that I put them inside a `minipage`. But the `minipage` grabs the `mdframed` footnotes.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{ProblemStatement}{
    \mdfsetup{
        innertopmargin=10pt,
        linewidth=0.4pt
    }
    \begin{mdframed}[]
    }
    {
    \end{mdframed}
    \bigskip
}   
\begin{document}
    % text
    \begin{ProblemStatement}
        Blah\footnote{footnote}

        \lipsum[1-4]

        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
        \captionof{table}{My table}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline 
            1& a \\ 
            \hline 
            2& b \\ 
            \hline 
            3& c \\ 
            \hline 
            4& d \\ 
            \hline 
            5& e \\ 
            \hline 
            6& f \\ 
            \hline 
            7& g \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular} 
        \end{center}
        \end{minipage}

        \lipsum[5-6]
    \end{ProblemStatement}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way make the caption and `tabular` stay together other than using a `minipage`? Is there a way to stop the `minipage` grabbing the footnotes? Is there an alternative for `mdframed`, where floats could be used freely?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to do this with `xepersian`'s `LTRfootnote`?

**MWE 2 (with XePersian)**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Nazli}
\setlatintextfont{Liberation Serif}


\begin{document}
    \begin{mdframed}
        Blah\footnote{پانویس}\LTRfootnote{footnote}
        \begin{LTR}
            \lipsum[1-5]
        \end{LTR}


        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \captionof{table}{جدول من}
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                    \hline 
                    1& a \\ 
                    \hline 
                    2& b \\ 
                    \hline 
                \end{tabular} 
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}

        \begin{LTR}
            \lipsum[5-6]
        \end{LTR}

    \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mdframed` shares the footnote internal macros with `minipage`, hence the footnote is collected inside `mdframed` and output by `minipage`. The following example makes `mdframed` use its individual footnote internals, hence the problem is avoided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Nazli}
\setlatintextfont{Liberation Serif}

\makeatletter
% emulate mpfootnote staff
\newinsert\@mdf@footins
\@definecounter{mdf@footnote}
\def\themdf@footnote{%
  % Currently, both LTR and RTL footnote numbers inside mdframed env are in
  % persian format, which raises errors like
  %     "missing character <persian char> in font <latin font>" 
  % in LTR footnotes. This might be a bug in my code, and I add \rl as a
  % workaround to force using persian text font for all footnote numbers.
  \rl{\itshape\@alph\c@mdf@footnote}}


\@ifpackageloaded{bidi}{
  \def\bidi@mdf@footnoterule{\footnoterule}

  \renewrobustcmd*\mdf@footnoteoutput{%
    \ifvoid\@mdf@footins\else
      \nobreak
      \vskip\mdf@footenotedistance@length
      \normalcolor
      \mdf@footnoterule
      \unvbox\@mdf@footins
    \fi
  }

  \renewrobustcmd*\mdf@footnoteinput{%
    \def\@mpfn{mdf@footnote}%
    \def\thempfn{\themdf@footnote}%
    \c@mdf@footnote\z@
    \let\@footnotetext\@mdf@footnotetext
    \let\@LTRfootnotetext\@mdf@LTRfootnotetext
    \let\@RTLfootnotetext\@mdf@RTLfootnotetext
  }

  % similar to \@mpTRLfootnotetext defined in footnote-xetex-bidi.def
  \long\def\@mdf@RTLfootnotetext#1{%
    \ifbidi@autofootnoterule\ifnum\c@mdf@f@footnote=\@ne\global\let\bidi@mdf@footnoterule\right@footnoterule\fi\fi%
    \global\setbox\@mdf@footins\vbox{\@RTLtrue%
      \unvbox\@mdf@footins
      \reset@font%
      \bidi@@RTLfootnotetext@font% \reset@font\footnotesize
      \hsize\columnwidth
      \@parboxrestore
      \protected@edef\@currentlabel
           {\csname p@mdf@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
      \color@begingroup
        \@makefntext{%
          \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
      \color@endgroup}}

  % similar to \@mpLTRfootnotetext defined in footnote-xetex-bidi.def
  \long\def\@mdf@LTRfootnotetext#1{%
   \ifbidi@autofootnoterule\ifnum\c@mdf@footnote=\@ne\global\let\bidi@mdf@footnoterule\left@footnoterule\fi\fi%
    \global\setbox\@mdf@footins\vbox{\@RTLfalse%
      \unvbox\@mdf@footins
      \reset@font%
      \bidi@@LTRfootnotetext@font% \reset@font\footnotesize
      \hsize\columnwidth
      \@parboxrestore
      \protected@edef\@currentlabel
           {\csname p@mdf@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
      \color@begingroup
        \@makefntext{%
          \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
      \color@endgroup}}
}{
  \renewrobustcmd*\mdf@footnoteoutput{%
    \ifvoid\@mdf@footins\else
      \nobreak
      \vskip\mdf@footenotedistance@length
      \normalcolor
      \mdf@footnoterule
      \unvbox\@mdf@footins
    \fi
  }

  \renewrobustcmd*\mdf@footnoteinput{%
    \def\@mpfn{mdf@footnote}%
    \def\thempfn{\themdf@footnote}%
    \c@mdf@footnote\z@
    \let\@footnotetext\@mdf@footnotetext
  }
}

\long\def\@mdf@footnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\@mdf@footins\vbox{%
    \unvbox\@mdf@footins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@mdf@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
        text in minipage\footnote{RTL footnote in minipage}\LTRfootnote{LTR footnote in minipage}
    \end{minipage}}

    \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=cyan]
      text in mdframed\footnote{RTL footnote 1 in mdframed}\LTRfootnote{LTR footnote 1 in mdframed}

      \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-\parindent}
          text in minipage, which is nested inside mdframed\footnote{RTL footnote in nested minipage}\LTRfootnote{LTR footnote in nested minipage}
      \end{minipage}}

      more text in mdframed\footnote{RTL footnote 2 in mdframed}\LTRfootnote{LTR footnote 2 in mdframed}
    \end{mdframed}

    normal text\footnote{RTL footnote}\LTRfootnote{LTR footnote}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I use this with `xepersian`'s `LTRfootnote`?

Comment: @Eliad Can you update the mwe to include usage of `xepersian`'s command?

Comment: I have edited the MWE.

Comment: @Eliad Answer updated.